# How do I run an external program?

Tags: c++, linux

I'm on Linux mint 12.

I want to run a program `usr/share/application/firefox` and then pass a string anywhere. I haven't found a solution for Linux but from what I've seen so far, there are many theories for Windows.

```
size_t ExecuteProcess(std::wstring FullPathToExe, std::wstring Parameters, size_t SecondsToWait) 
{ 
    size_t iMyCounter = 0, iReturnVal = 0, iPos = 0; 
    DWORD dwExitCode = 0; 
    std::wstring sTempStr = L""; 

    /* - NOTE - You should check here to see if the exe even exists */ 

    /* Add a space to the beginning of the Parameters */ 
    if (Parameters.size() != 0) 
    { 
        if (Parameters[0] != L' ') 
        { 
            Parameters.insert(0,L" "); 
        } 
    } 

    /* The first parameter needs to be the exe itself */ 
    sTempStr = FullPathToExe; 
    iPos = sTempStr.find_last_of(L"\\"); 
    sTempStr.erase(0, iPos +1); 
    Parameters = sTempStr.append(Parameters); 

     /* CreateProcessW can modify Parameters thus we allocate needed memory */ 
    wchar_t * pwszParam = new wchar_t[Parameters.size() + 1]; 
    if (pwszParam == 0) 
    { 
        return 1; 
    } 
    const wchar_t* pchrTemp = Parameters.c_str(); 
    wcscpy_s(pwszParam, Parameters.size() + 1, pchrTemp); 

    /* CreateProcess API initialization */ 
    STARTUPINFOW siStartupInfo; 
    PROCESS_INFORMATION piProcessInfo; 
    memset(&siStartupInfo, 0, sizeof(siStartupInfo)); 
    memset(&piProcessInfo, 0, sizeof(piProcessInfo)); 
    siStartupInfo.cb = sizeof(siStartupInfo); 

    if (CreateProcessW(const_cast<LPCWSTR>(FullPathToExe.c_str()), 
                            pwszParam, 0, 0, false, 
                            CREATE_DEFAULT_ERROR_MODE, 0, 0, 
                            &siStartupInfo, &piProcessInfo) != false) 
    { 
         /* Watch the process. */ 
        dwExitCode = WaitForSingleObject(piProcessInfo.hProcess, (SecondsToWait * 1000)); 
    } 
    else 
    { 
        /* CreateProcess failed */ 
        iReturnVal = GetLastError(); 
    } 

    /* Free memory */ 
    delete[]pwszParam; 
    pwszParam = 0; 

    /* Release handles */ 
    CloseHandle(piProcessInfo.hProcess); 
    CloseHandle(piProcessInfo.hThread); 

    return iReturnVal; 
}
```

You can see many theories [here](http://goffconcepts.com/techarticles/development/cpp/createprocess.html) the first answer describes how to get it done for Linux with C, I want to do it with C++, I've been googling for hours and i saw many *theories*. This subject appears to have more theories than quantum physics `:)`

I am a Python guy, because I like simplicity, so please give a simple code that would work on 32 and 64 bit if possible.

I would like to do something like if `usr/share/application/firefox` is available, run it, else run `usr/share/application/googlechrome`

And would you please tell me why can't the same code run on Mac and Windows?

Comment: I started editing this, but I think there's just too much wrong with it to salvage. Can you clean it up, including adding basic capitalisation and spelling? What is your question? This is not a webforum or a "give me the code" site.

Comment: Anything done in C can (almost always) also be done in C++, so finding a solution in C will still almost always compile with C++ as well. There also appears to be *more than one question here*.

Comment: If you're using std::wstring then the "c" tag is a bit wrong.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I think the answer of  ildjarn is what i need

Comment: maybe not coz he deleted his answer! strange

Comment: There is no answer to this "question", deleted or otherwise.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit a user called **ildjarn** left a comment about [this link](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0/libs/filesystem/v3/doc/index.htm) then he deleted his comment

Comment: @AndrewMarshall if you can just answer **how to open an external program** and ignore the other questions, I'll be grateful, i told you about what i have to do but that does not mean that you have to answer everything

Comment: @user: OK, so a comment not an answer.

Comment: From what you ask it seems more like you want to open a web site: in that case you should call `xdg-open` instead of a particular browser.

Comment: @MatteoItalia no i want to open an application, firefox was just an example

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This can be done using either `system` which is the same as calling `os.system` in Python or `fork` and `execl` or `popen` which is similar to calling `subprocess.Popen` in Python.

Some examples are shown below. 
They should work on Linux or Mac.

For Windows use _system and _popen instead, using if defined function of the C preprocessor.

**IFDEF Example**

```
#ifdef __unix__ /* __unix__ is usually defined by compilers targeting Unix systems */
# callto system goes here
#elif defined _WIN32 /* _Win32 is usually defined by compilers targeting 32 or 64 bit Windows   systems */
# callto _system goes here
#endif
```

They are architecture dependent, though the location of the firefox binary may not be on various systems.

**system**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    system("/usr/share/application/firefox");
    printf("Command done!");
    return 0;
}
```

**popen**

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(int argc, char **argv))
{
   FILE *fpipe;
   char *command="/usr/share/application/firefox";
   char line[256];

   if ( !(fpipe = (FILE*)popen(command,"r")) )
   {  // If fpipe is NULL
      perror("Problems with pipe");
      exit(1);
   }

   while ( fgets( line, sizeof line, fpipe))
   {
     printf("%s", line);
   }
   pclose(fpipe);
   return 0;
}
```