# Is it possible to execute another program using C++?

Tags: c++

What I'd like to do is have my C++ code open up Mplus (statistical program that I've downloaded on my computer) and run it. Is it possible?

Comment: The answer to this is OS dependent. Which OSes are you targeting?

Comment: Please look at [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9550488/how-do-i-run-an-external-program][1]. It explains the same issue.


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9550488/how-do-i-run-an-external-program

Comment: It is always possible that if you try to describe what you are attempting to achieve, someone could recommend a better way of accomplishing your goal.

Comment: is it worth it to make a program just for that ? why not just write a shell script  ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may be able to do what you want with std::system() calls like:

```
std::system("program -e input_commands.txt"); // Assuming it accepts some sort of command line args
std::system("program < input_commands.txt"); // Assuming it responds to stdin
```

It depends on the program if this approach will work.